# Static Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, lua

Okay, so I know that static virtual functions don't exist for several reasons.  I do believe, however, I have found a situation in which something mimicking them may be useful.  As part of a group project for a class we must design a scripting core for a game engine.  In order to keep things decoupled we want a class to be able to register its metatables (functions, members, etc) with the LuaState.  Also, I could be way off here as this is my first time trying to implement anything of the sort.

So, in order to keep things generic we have an IScriptStateManager interface that contains pure virtual functions to register objects with the scripting languages global state, perform init and shutdown features, and has a couple other functions for DoFile and DoString.  Then we have a LuaStateManager class that implements the functionality of this interface.

Now, in order to allow most game objects to be created in script without knowing about them ahead of time we also created an IScriptObject interface.  If you want an object to be represented by the scripting system it should implement this interface.  This interface includes a method that contains a method called register that derived classes can implement and will set up there metatables. So everything looks like this:

```
bool LuaStateManager::Register(IScriptObject* obj)
{
    if (obj has not already been registered with global state)
    {
          obj->Register();   
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm sure you can see the problem.  First and foremost we need and actual instantiation to register an object.  Because of this we may be calling this function multiple times for a particular type of object, only to have it return true the first time and false every other time.  While the overhead of this is minimal, it's a dead giveaway that something is wrong with the design.

So the issue arises.  In this particular case we need the functionality of both a static method and a virtual method.  Granted we could simply manually add static methods to each class and then call those once, but this couples objects to the scripting system.  Any tips or help would be most welcome.  Thanks

Comment: I have seen this pattern before at my work. There is a clean solution for it too. This works only if you'll ever have at most one sub-class of `IScriptStateManager`. If that condition is true in your application, I'll be glad to elaborate the solution in an answer.

Comment: @RSahu You can still share the method; it might help the OP to think of a newer (/better) way for the job.

Comment: @RSahu For this particular project there will only be one subclass, but we would like it to work in such a way that, for example, a PythonStateManager could be added in the future.  As hjpotter92 above me said, however, I would still love to hear the solution as it may give me some insight on a better way to approach the problem. As I said this is my first foray into building a scripting system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide access to the functionality of IScriptStateManager through a set of functions in an API class or a namespace.

ScriptStateManagerAPI.h:

```
namespace ScriptStateManagerAPI
{
   // Function to register the active ScriptStateManager.
   void setActiveScriptStateManager(IScriptStateManager* scriptStateManager);

   // Function to register a ScriptObject.
   bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj);
}
```

IScriptStateManager.h:

```
class IScriptStateManager
{
   virtual bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj) = 0;
};
```

ScriptStateManagerAPI.cpp:

```
#include <IScriptStateManager.h>

namespace ScriptStateManagerAPI
{
   static IScriptStateManager* activeScriptStateManager = nullptr;

   void setActiveScripStatetManager(IScriptStateManager* scriptStateManager)
   {
      activeScriptStateManager = scriptStateManager;
   }

   bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj)
   {
      if ( activeScriptStateManager )
      {
         return activeScriptStateManager->registerScriptObject(obj);
      }
      else
      {
         // Deal with lack of an active IScriptStateManager.
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

LuaScriptManager.h:

```
#include <IScriptStateManager.h>

class LuaScriptManager : public IScriptStateManager
{
   virtual bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj);
};
```

LuaScriptManager.cpp:

```
namespace
{
   // Helper class in anonymous namespace to register a LuaScriptManager as
   // the active IScriptStateManager at start up time.
   struct Initializer
   {
      Initializer();
   };
};

// Construct an Initializer at start up time.
static Initializer initializer;

Initializer::Initializer()
{
   // Register a LuaScriptManager as the acive ScriptStateManager.
   ScriptStateAPI::setActiveScriptStateManager(new LuaScriptManager());
}

bool LuaScriptManager::registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj)
{
   if (obj has not already been registered with global state)
   {
      obj->Register();   
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

You can use another `ScriptStateManager` in your application. Then you have to choose whether you can have only one `ScriptStateManager` at a time or not. If your application needs more than one `ScriptStateManager` at a time, you can change the `static` data as well as the interface in `ScriptStateManagerAPI`

ScriptStateManagerAPI.h:

```
namespace ScriptStateManagerAPI
{
   // Function to register an active ScriptStateManager.
   void registerActiveScriptStateManager(IScriptStateManager* scriptStateManager);

   // Function to register a ScriptObject.
   bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj);
}
```

ScriptStateManagerAPI.cpp:

```
#include <IScriptStateManager.h>

namespace ScriptStateManagerAPI
{
   static std::set<IScriptStateManager*> activeScriptStateManagers;

   void registerActiveScripStatetManager(IScriptStateManager* scriptStateManager)
   {
      activeScriptStateManagers.insert(scriptStateManager);
   }

   bool registerScriptObject(IScriptObject* obj)
   {
      // Figure out how to manage the return the values of each
      // activeScriptManager.
      for ( auto activeScriptManager, activeScriptStateManagers)
      {
         activeScriptManager->registerScriptObject(obj);
      }
      return true; //????
   }
}
```